# Maven tomcat:redeploy packages needlessly

Tags: maven-2, tomcat, maven

I'm using [Tomcat Maven plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/index.html) to deploy my war to Tomcat. When I run

```
mvn tomcat:redeploy
```

I notice that the packaging goal is always executed, even if it was run and no change was made. How can I skip that goal and only run the deployment itself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it reads on [the Tomcat plugin documentation](http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html) page:

> Deploy a WAR to Tomcat witjout forking the package lifecycle

The simple command:

```
mvn tomcat:deploy-only
```

should deploy your web application without executing the `package` lifecycle.

Comment: Yeah, found it also 2 minutes ago :) Thanks.

Comment: Thanks.  I was running into an issue with the redeploy goal not properly filtering a resource file that had `${parent.project.artifactId}` as a property value.  It would build correctly using `package`, so running `mvn clean package tomcat:undeploy tomcat:deploy-only` resolved me issue :-)